# How to access all flags and get their values using loop in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to write all flags and its values in external file(like txt).
How can I get automatically all the contents inside `tf.flag`?
is there any built-in function? or is there easy way e.g. by using loop?

for example,

```
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("device","/gpu:0", "select device")
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("rnn_size","64", "number of units")
```

I want to get

```
device /gpu:0 
rnn_size 64
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/platform/flags.py), it appears the API doesn't support it directly. If you need a hack, you can use `tf.flags.FLAGS.__flags` to get the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks! I have one more question. When I tried to access dictionary key and values using for loop (`for key, value in tf.flags.FLAGS.__flags`) and then print, nothing was shown. It seems the dictionary was empty. But after I access one key(e.g. `print tf.flags.FLAGS.device`) then I could access to all the keys and values using previous "for loop". Do you know why it is so?

Comment: @thang `for key, value in tf.flags.FLAGS.__flags.items()`

Answer (score 27):

For tensorflow 1.5 you can use `tf.app.flags.FLAGS.flag_values_dict()` they have changed the flags library one more time

Answer (score 0):

The complete code is shown below:

tf 1.13

```py
# get flags
for attr,flag_obj in tf.FLAGS.__flags.items():
    print("attr:%s\tvalue:%s" % (attr, flag_obj.value))
```

I see no body mentions about the value of key in `__flags` is `flag object`, it can not print readable value.